# How can i create an route for search article?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to create a route to search an article

should be able to add the size or the page

like this

```
'/post/1/article/search?size=200&page=1
```

it will be good like this?

```
get '/post/:id/article/search/:size/:page
```

can i create that endpoint directly with rails?

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :articles
          get /search/:size/:page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```rb
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :posts do
      resources :articles do
        collection do 
          get "/search/:size/:page", action: :search, defaults: { size: 200, page: 1 }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In your controller, you'll be able to access via: `params[:size]` and `params[:page]`.

**NOTES**

- If you just need to send as regular parameters `?size=200&page=1`, you don't need to define the parameters in the route itself. The "querystring" was always sent to Rails controllers:

```rb
collection do 
  get :search
end
```

- The `defaults` are not mandatory, but in such case I think it's a good idea as you will always have a fallback value for those parameters.
- You can read further details in the official guides:

  - "*collection*" routes: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes
  - "*non-resourceful*" routes: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes

Comment: how can i designate the function controller in this case get :search ?

Comment: By default, `get :search` => maps to "search" action in your controller. If you need this path to target a different action, you can do it by: `get :search, action: :my_search`. Don't forget you have the `./bin/rails routes` command to print all your routing setup in the terminal.